# Volley SSL Handshake Exception although has removed SSL3 protocol

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-volley

I want to make volley https request, and I have use code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78187) to remove SSL3 protocol and using TLSv1.2 for android >=4.4 and TLS for Android<4.4, but sometimes when I make request this error appear :

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated:
>   ssl=0x606cfb30: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>
> error:1409443E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert inappropriate
>   fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x5fee2098:0x00000003)

anybody can help ?

Note : That error only appear in some device with Android 4.4, some other device with Android 4.4 is working well without that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found it by myself, that just the problem when using slow connection, so when the connection timeout volley handshake will failed (volley connection time out is so fast), so I try  to added Volley time out to 10000 ms, like this :

```
jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

And now my app working in device that use slow connection too.