# Android Volley SSL error

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-volley

am using two nested volley requests at the same server but the second one returns with error :

```
        StringRequest strReqUpdate = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, versionCheckURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            initJson = response;
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(initJson);
                final long version = root.getLong("latest_update");                  
                long localVersion = prefs.getLong("version", 0);
                boolean flag = false;

                if(version != localVersion){                    
                        flag = true;
                }

                if(flag == true){                     
                    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {                               
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("json", response);                                                                                              
                            editor.putLong("version", version);
                            editor.commit();

                            parseData(response); 
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            String cachedResponse = prefs.getString("json", "");

                            if (!cachedResponse.equals("")) {
                                parseData(cachedResponse);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.network_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            headers.put("key", getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));
                            return headers;
                        }
                    };
                    strReq.setShouldCache(false);
                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, Constants.TAG_STRING_REQ);
                }
                else{                       
                    String cachedResponse = prefs.getString("json", "");
                    if (!cachedResponse.equals("")) {
                        parseData(cachedResponse);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.network_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String cachedResponse = prefs.getString("json", "");
            if (!cachedResponse.equals("")) {
                parseData(cachedResponse);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.network_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("key",getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));
            return headers;
        }
    }; 
    strReqUpdate.setShouldCache(false);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReqUpdate, Constants.TAG_STRING_REQ);
```

what am doing here is making a request to see if there is an update to my JSON and if there is start a request to fetch it(if not get cashed JSON). Both requests are to a heroku server with ssl but only second request throws an error. I think am getting an ssl error, I even tried to over-wright the ssl handshake as seen from various posts but nothing works.

The second request isolated is :

```
         StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {                               
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("json", response);                                                                                              
                        editor.putLong("version", version);
                        editor.commit();

                        parseData(response); 
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        String cachedResponse = prefs.getString("json", "");

                        if (!cachedResponse.equals("")) {
                            parseData(cachedResponse);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.network_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("key", getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                strReq.setShouldCache(false);
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, Constants.TAG_STRING_REQ);
```

What am getting on log :

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException:  SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0x61ff28f0:  Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>                                                                         error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3  alert
>   handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744
>   0x5df0b6fd:0x00000000)

Comment: ??? [you can't make two SSL connection at same time](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46988/is-it-technically-possible-to-configure-two-different-ssl-certificates-for-the-s). you can disconnect and connect again or you can use one ssl connection with two request but you should pay attention to [this issue](http://serverfault.com/questions/566426/does-each-subdomain-need-its-own-ssl-certificate).

Comment: Am not making 2 SSL connections at the same time, the second one starts in onResponse of the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED : what looked like an **SSL** error was in fact a timeout of the connection.

```
jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

setting the request at 10 seconds and MAX_RETIES did the trick as seen in :

[Volley SSL Handshake Exception although has removed SSL3 protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259090/volley-ssl-handshake-exception-although-has-removed-ssl3-protocol?rq=1)